# How to use mypy with helper functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function `my_function` that takes two arguments, `x` and `method`. Depending on the value of `method`, either one of two standalone functions will be used, `func1` and `func2`. These two functions take `x` as argument: `func1` expects it to be an integer and `func2` expects it to be a float. Both functions may be used independently by the user and thus check the type of `x` and raise an error if the type is wrong. Below is my code with type hints:

```py
from typing import Literal

def func1(x: int):
    """Perform some work on integers."""
    if not isinstance(x, int):
        raise ValueError("x should be an integer.")
    
    # Do some stuff.

def func2(x: float):
    """Perform some work on floats."""
    if not isinstance(x, float):
        raise ValueError("x should be a float.")
    
    # Do some stuff.

def my_function(x: int | float, method: Literal[1, 2]):
    """Perform some work using one of two methods."""

    match method:
        case 1:
            result = func1(x)
        case 2:
            result = func2(x)
        case _:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid method: {method}.")

    # Do some more work on result.

    return result
```

Mypy will raise an error on the call to `func1`, as the `int | float` type from `x` is incompatible with the expected type `int` from `helper1`. What's the recommended way to please mypy here? Should I repeat the type checking in `my_function` just before calling `func1` and `func2`?

**EDIT**: I should note that I do not want to simply rely on the type of `x` inside `my_function` to choose between functions, as it would be very easy for users to confuse integer and floats (e.g. by omitting the `.0` in `1.0`).

Comment: You'll need `cast` and `overloads` - the former to please `mypy` (it doesn't rely on function overloads now when checking its body), the latter to communicate to end users the real expected types. Your code is very non-standard (I'd say non-pythonic TBH, since you have explicit type checks in functions, and common practice would be have two functions for two different actions, given that they do different things - it's a single responsibility principle). [playground example](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=bb984a8cd85fe0f5259f8e4f541d56b6)

Comment: "Should I repeat the type checking in my_function just before calling func1 and func2?" yes. This is how *nominal typing works*. If you tell the function it accepts type `X`, then the static analysis will complain if you pass type `Y` (that is not a subtype of `X`) to the function.

Comment: @STerliakov: Thanks, your answer is exactly what I was looking for! I should have read the documentation of the `typing` module more carefully. I would also be interested to know how you would refactor my example code to be more Pythonic. Would you separate `my_function` into two independent functions, one for each method? And maybe implement a new helper that performs "# Do some more work on result"? Also, is it non-Pythonic to explicitly check types? Even without this, I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you post it as such!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the reference! I knew this would solve mypy's error, but I was wondering if it was good practice.

Comment: @Biblot yes. exactly: I'd treat `func1` and `func2` as public functions and extract "do some work" into another public function, and caller will call either `func1` or `func2` and  then `do_more_stuff`. This will be understandable for `mypy` and adhere to common design principles better.

Comment: Thanks! If you'd like to summarize both your comments in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your concern. But even by using if type() it can be achieved.

```
import math

def my_function(x):
    cond = type(x) == int or type(x) == float

    if cond:
        flr = math.floor(x)
        if x % flr == 0:
            result = func1(x)
        
        else:
            result = func2(x)
     else:
        return 'Invalid Method'

    #perform some task with result here
```

The idea here is instead of asking the machine to decide whether the number is integer or float, we do that part as well in our coding. From the argument, Leaving off the decimal portion, let us take the whole number part. if it is a decimal, if we divide the number with whole number part, there will be a reminder. Whereas if it is a non-decimal, there will not be any reminder.

As you split up this into 2 functions, I also have done so. As long as you are not using funct1 and func2 anywhere else except in my_function, you don't need to create func1 and func2. These can be integrated inside my_function itself

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work: as I've said in my original post, `func1` and `func2` are standalone functions, and the `method` argument of `my_function` is required to avoid any confusion between integers and floats by the user.

Comment: It works. Pl check if there is any type error.

[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/mvrcppP.png)

Comment: By not working, I meant that your answer does not meet my requirements. Specifically, I indicated that I didn't want to rely on the type of `x` to choose between `func1` and `func2` because of user errors.

Comment: I understand what you meant by user error. In the above coding even if the user omits 0  after decimal, it will work properly. The user can mention an integer as 1 or 1.0 or 1.00 or whatever way the want. Even then, this will be considered as integer only.

Comment: I've used type here only for the purpose of omitting other types like str or list. Not to find out whether it is float or int.

Answer (score 0):

Since your parameter in `helper1()` can take x of type int or float you should also use `def helper1(x: int | float):`. This will satisfy mypy and meets the expectations of your code. Same for `helper2()`.

Comment: But when using `helper1` as a standalone function, wouldn't this be confusing for the user? The type hints of `helper1` would contradict the documentation (that says that `x` must be an integer). Also, one of the advantages of having `x: int` in `helper1` is that most IDEs will show a warning to the user in scripts/notebook when passing a float without even executing the code.

Comment: yes your structure of the code is indeed confusing for the user. Maybe rethink it from scratch but unfortunately this wont be the right place to ask for further advice. since you would need to list all your requirements and so on and the answer would be opinion based

Comment: Isn't there any general recommendation (either from a PEP, from mypy, or anything else) about this kind of structure? I feel like functions calling helpers based on argument type is a pretty common programming pattern that should be easily annotated using type hints.

Comment: well the problem still is that your helpers dont make sense and not the annotation for using type hints. i think youve to rethink what your helpers want todd. to they want to check for int/float ? or do they want to make furthers calculations with these arguments. if you try to let your helpers do 2 jobs at once then you will get a result like this. a confusing user experience

Comment: I think I may have used the term "helper" incorrectly. Both "helpers" here are standalone functions that are user-facing. They performs some work and must test that their input are valid to avoid printing cryptic error messages to the user. That said, `my_function` builds upon the same logic from either one of these two "helpers". It seems logical to call them instead of rewriting the whole logic inside `my_function`. It seemed to me that since these helpers already checked the type of `x`, it wasn't necessary to repeat this step inside `my_function`, but maybe that is required for Mypy?

Comment: To answer your question, these "helper" should check their input type **and** perform some work using this input, since they can be used as standalones by the user. Would you instead add another helper just for the type checking? Wouldn't I need to call this new helper both in the helper **and** in `my_function`?

I've updated my example to clarify.